# Select a row without set AutoGenerateSelectButton to true

Tags: asp.net

How to select a row without set `AutoGenerateSelectButton` to true and check selectedIndex in  `GridView_SelectedIndexChanged`?

How to recognize that user select specific field on table (for example selected row2,col3)

Comment: how do you want to select the row? by clicking on it?

Comment: ye i want to select it by clicking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an average gridview with no select button. The RowDataBound method makes your grid highlightable. You can check if a certain column was selected possibly with if conditions in your SelectedIndexChanged method as that will tell you what row was selected and then you can get a value from a specific column based on the order your columns were made as shown below. This wont show exactly where they clicked x and y but should head you in the right direction I think. This will however get column data based on what row was highlighted and clicked on with a post back of course.

```
<asp:GridView ID="PropertyGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PropertyGridView_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="PropertyGridView_RowDataBound">
                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="EtLbl" Text="No properties were found."</asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="User Name" Width="20%" /> </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="User Age" Width="20%" /> </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Height" HeaderText="User Height" Width="20%" /> </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


public void PropertyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.DataItemIndex == -1) 
        return;
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "this.style.cursor='hand';");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick",    this.GetPostBackClientEvent(PropertyGridView,"Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
}

public void PropertyGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string Name = PropertyGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    string Age= PropertyGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    string Height PropertyGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;

    if( Height != null)
    {
         // The user selected a row and this Column ( Height has data )
    }


}
```

Comment: please delete your answer that i delete this question

Answer (score 0):

Add a column with a button (using a template field) and set the CommandName to "Select".  That should work.

Comment: in this way user can see button and it's bad

Comment: Ok, that was unclear in what you mentioned above, do you want to select a row by clicking on the row, or a cell, or how does the select get triggered?